# ipynb: highlight other occurrences of selected variable in VSCode ipython notebooks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting

In other languages, VSCode highlights occurences of the selected variable.

In the below [Elixir language](https://elixir-lang.org/) code example, my cursor is on the variable `pid` in the 2nd line, but the other occurrence (in the first line) is also highlighted:

[image: var pid highlighted]

How can I achieve this with `.ipynb` files?

Comment: Sorry, but they are one and the same parameter, when you cursor on the variable 'pid', all the 'pid' in this function should be highlighted. Or I am misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT The example I provided is Elixir code - the same behaviour doesn't occur with `.ipynbs`. How do I get this behaviour with `.ipynbs`?

Comment: could you find a solution to this? I am still looking for an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but do you mean this?

[image]

[image]

My Jupyter and the python file always work like this.

Comment: I wonder what extension might be causing this to not work for my files right now. :/